# C++ Selection for Array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to teach myself C++ through a book I picked up. One of the exercises is to get an user-inputted array of colours as string objects. Then they say to implement a selection sort on the user-inputted colours using relational operators. I have already started on what I think is the right track, but I have hit a road block and I am not sure what is wrong with it. It compiles, it just won't return the sorted vales (I think) Any assistance with what I have already would be greatly appreciated

```
void selectionSort(char [], int);
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 80;
    char colour[SIZE];

    cout << "Enter the names of five kinds of fruit:" << endl;
    cin.getline(colour, SIZE);

    cout << colour << endl;
    selectionSort(colour, SIZE);

    cout << colour << endl;
    return 0;
}
// SORT
void selectionSort(char shade[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;


    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = shade[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {    
            if (shade[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = shade[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        shade[minIndex] = shade[startScan];
        shade[startScan] = minValue;
    }
    cout << shade[size] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The very first problem is that your array needs to contain std::strings, not chars. There's lots more to talk about after you fix that.

Comment: @MarkRansom - so instead of 'char colour[SIZE]' it should be 'string colour[SIZE]' ?? THanks

Comment: You also need to loop your input 5 times - right now it only gets the input till the enter key is pressed.

Comment: @JanS - a sample user input would be 'green red blue yellow orange'

Comment: @jooMLA, you'd be correct if SIZE were 5. You're going to need a little more logic to break an input of a single line into 5 different items.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectionSort seems fine, but there is a problem when you call it.

```
selectionSort(colour, SIZE);
```

Here you tell your algorithm to sort the SIZE chars from colour, since SIZE is 80, it will sort the 80 first characters, but you ask the user to type only five characters (here I am assuming that the user should input 5 first letters of colors, if you expect the user to type the color name you should read 5 strings, not 5 chars).

If the user input have 5 characters, colour[5] will have the nil-terminator, which is 0, and will be at colour[0] after the sort, which will result in an empty string.

Try sorting only the letters you want:

```
selectionSort(colour, strlen(colour));
```

Comment: I believe they want actual words i.e. green red etc.  Will your suggestion still work if that is the case?

Comment: @jooMLA your selectionSort is sorting the characters from colour, if the user type "green red", it will mix everything and the result will be " deeegnrr". If you want to sort strings, you have two options: slipt the words after you read the line or read each word in one line and sort the lines, not the chars.

Answer (score 0):

I have to subscribe a motion to ban all the books that teach C++ with `iostream` and `char[]`.
They are incoherent.

If std::string is retained a "complex type" what the hell `cout` is?
If `cout` is retained a "basic object to start with", so `std::string` should.